# Expansion of a time series dataset in python by comparing the dates of previous rows and expanding the interval

Tags: python

I have a dataset -

```
Id  Date        Amount

1   1-Mar-20    100

1   18-Apr-20   120

1   22-Jun-20   200

1   30-Jul-20   400
```

**Expected Output is :**

```
Expanded Date          Id       Amount

1-Mar-20               1        100

2-Mar-20               1        100

3-Mar-20               1        100

4-Mar-20               1        100

5-Mar-20               1        100

6-Mar-20               1        100

7-Mar-20               1        100

8-Mar-20               1        100

.

.

18-Apr-20              1        120

19-Apr-20              1        120
```

and so on...

I have already tried -

```
newdf = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'Id':
                row.Id,
                'Date':
                pd.date_range(row.Date, row.Date.shift(-1), freq='D'),
                'Amount':
                row.Amount,
              
             
            },
            columns=['Id', 'Date', 'Amount'])
        for i, row in df.iterrows()
    ],
    ignore_index=True)
```

But its giving `'str' object has no attribute 'shift'`

Also I tried to resample data-

```
df.asfreq(freq='D', method='ffill')
```

But I am getting -

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'
```

Any pointers on how to expand this dataset comparing the 'Date' column as a Dataframe would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asfreq` works on the index, which is an int in your case, so the 'D' freq doesn't work. You can make your example work by setting the date as the index:

```py
>>> df = df.set_index(['Date'])
>>> filled = df.asfreq(freq='D', method='ffill')
>>> print(filled)
            Amount
Date              
2020-03-01     100
2020-03-02     100
2020-03-03     100
2020-03-04     100
2020-03-05     100
...            ...
2020-07-26     200
2020-07-27     200
2020-07-28     200
2020-07-29     200
2020-07-30     400

[152 rows x 1 columns]
```